# Not enough disk space while installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I am running ubuntu in a dual boot with windows 11. While installing ubuntu, it says that required space: 19GB (Ubuntu 23.04) Remaining Space: 0B. But, I have enough space to install ubuntu in my computer. How to fix this problem?

My ios file:    ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu 23.04 product you're asking about; but the recommended *minimum requirement* for Ubuntu Desktop has been 25GB since Ubuntu 17.10 (ie. all releases using the GNOME 3 Desktop).  If you're installing a desktop system you're below the recommended minimum at 19GB.

Comment: Also please be specific; for Ubuntu 23.04 there are different ISOs available that use the `ubuntu-desktop-installer`, `ubiquity`, `subiquity` and also for *flavors* some use `calamares`.  You've not given details as to what Ubuntu 23.04 product thus which ISOs choices (*which pick the installer you'll use*) you had available & which you opted to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Did you shrink your Windows partition to make space for a new Ubuntu partition? What is the status of your Ubuntu partition?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not create the free space from windows before to start the installation process of ubuntu.
Try to follow this guide:
[link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-linux-dual-booting-tutorial/)

Comment: Your answer is without any specifics; being only a link to another site (ie. possible spam).  Your answer should provide details as to an answer, with link only required for additional (*optional*) details or source, such that your answer alone is all that is required.